# Getting the Memory Error Wile saving file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

While Running through the lots of file getting the memory error at some point,Is there a way to handle it,Is i am handling the files in wrong way or there is any other way of doing it

**Here is my code i tried so far**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
import os




opco=['msd','ped','med','suy_consol','sidy','giser','sdisa']

print("Start reading the template file\n")

wb = load_workbook(filename='template_patch_debt.xlsx',data_only =True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws1=wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = 'vuln_export'
ws1.title='device_export'
print('###########Done Reading  the Template File#######'+'/n')
print('#########Start Reading The CSV File#############')

filelist_device=[f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".csv") and 'device' in f]
filelist_patch=[f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".csv") and 'patch' in f]
for file_device in filelist_device:
    for file_patch in filelist_patch:
        for opco_name in opco:
            if opco_name in file_device and opco_name in file_patch:
                print(opco_name)
                print("Start Reading for the device file for:"+file_device+'\n')
                df_1 = pd.read_csv(file_device)
                for r in dataframe_to_rows(df_1, index=False, header=True):
                    ws1.append(r)
                
            
                print("Start reading patch_debt file :-"+file_patch+'\n')
                df = pd.read_csv(file_patch)
                for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
                    ws.append(r)
                wb.save((file_patch.rsplit('_',1)[0] +'_debt_measure' '.xlsx'))
                wb.close()
                
                for row in ws:
                    for cell in row:
                        cell.value = None
                for row in ws1:
                    for cell in row:
                        cell.value = None
```

**Here is the Error i am getting**

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a60a13cb6158> in <module>
     41                 for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
     42                     ws.append(r)
---> 43                 wb.save((file_patch.rsplit('_',1)[0] +'_debt_measure' '.xlsx'))
     44                 wb.close()
```

Comment: You're closing the workbook inside the for loop, then you're going to cycle back in the next iteration and try to access wb again

Comment: Yes ,I am doing in that way,Actualy i am copying the data from two diff csv sheets in that template and saving it by filename.xlsx

Comment: What I meant is that maybe you're getting the error on wb.save **because** you closed wb, that would make sense. Have you tried closing only after the for loop ?

Comment: yes i tried, It is overriding the data

Comment: Is there is a way to handle it